# How can I vectorize the entropy calculation?

Tags: matlab, vectorization, probability-theory

I was trying to the entropy for every column, the matrix looks like this:

```
0.5 0.3333 0.2  
0   0.3333 0.4  
0.5 0.3333 0.4
```

Every column add up to one, however, there's some zeros in the matrix, so if I just log2(arr(i,:)), there will be an -Inf in the result so the whole thing won't work
In practice I have a huge matrix, so I want the program to run fast, is there a work around?
Here's my solution, does it works as fast as p .* log2(p)?

```
    log2p = log2(p);
    log2p(log2p==-Inf)=0;
    entropy = entropy - p .* log2p;
```

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly you want to do, but you can add epsilon (0.001) to the matrix, so it will not contain zeros.

Comment: @Adiel I want to calculate entropy for every column, what you said is a work around

Comment: @cloudyFan your question is not clear, what are you trying to vectorize? and how `-inf` is related to your vectorization problem?

Comment: How physically meaningful is it to force something that has an entropy of negative infinity to **zero**? I mean, is `-> 0` the correct remedy here? Why not leave them `-inf` or make them `NaN`?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis the `inf`s are intermidate results: the actual entropy is `-p*log2(p)` - and has `0*inf` definition problem when `p=0`. For this **specific** formula, in this **specific** context, `0*inf` should equal `0`. So, there is no need for `inf`s or `NaN`s.

Comment: @Shai: Ah, I was blinded by the logarithm and forgot the multiplication :) Obviously, [the limit value of the product is zero](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+h*log2%28h%29+for+h+to+zero).

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis logarithm can make you blind - ocupational hazard, I guess...

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB `0^0` is equal to `1`. And since `log2(1)==0`, You can use this and rewrite your entropy function as

```
p.*log2(p) = log2(p.^p)
```

Then for your example we get

```
>> log2(p.^p)

ans =

   -0.5000   -0.5283   -0.4644
         0   -0.5283   -0.5288
   -0.5000   -0.5283   -0.5288
```

Comment: You really get `0.^0 == 0`? Which version of Matlab? I get `1` in R2012b and `1` is [the standard in most languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Zero_to_the_power_of_zero) (some leave it undefined or give errors).

Answer (score 0):

Use `isinf`

```
log2p = log2(p);
log2p( isinf(log2p) ) = 0;
entrpoy = -sum( p.*log2p , 1 )
```

Comment: is this as fast is the vectorized version?entropy = entropy - p .* log2(p);

Comment: in your statement: `entropy = entropy - p.*log2(p);` what is vectorized? where `entropy` comes from? is it a line in a `for`-loop over all rows of `p`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `eps`:

eps is minimum representable number in float so you will have your results without changing much(almost infinitesmall change).

```
log2(p)

ans =

   -1.0000   -1.5851   -2.3219
      -Inf   -1.5851   -1.3219
   -1.0000   -1.5851   -1.3219

log2(p+eps)

ans =

   -1.0000   -1.5851   -2.3219
  -52.0000   -1.5851   -1.3219
   -1.0000   -1.5851   -1.3219

p2=p+eps;
 entropy=-sum(p2.*log2(p2),1)

entropy =

    1.0000    1.5849    1.5219
```

Comment: But it gives reasonable results for entropy(1.0000)?

Comment: nevermind, I made a conceptual mistake. See my comment to Shai in the question comments above :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `isnan` in combination with the fact that `0*-inf==NaN`:

```
E = p.*log2(p);

valid = ~isnan(E);
entropy(valid) = entropy(valid) - E(valid);

clear E valid
```

As found [here](http://www.dynare.org/DynareWiki/MatlabVersionsCompatibility), this should work without warnings if you have MATLAB newer than R2007a.